# import not working for xsd

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I am a bit new to XSD, I tried updating a XSD and it is giving me the below error
Code i have added:

```
<xs:element ref="cards:paymentrelationship" />
```

For this i have added below thing to the xml:schema

```
xml:cads="uri"
```

and below import statement

```
<xs:import namespace="cads" schemalocation="uri"/>
```

i am getting the below error

```
componenets from this namespace are not referencable from this xsd , appropriate import tag needs to be added
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the `cards` text is a **namespace-prefix** that you are using in the xsd.

The *namespace-prefix* must be associated to an **namespace-value** (here "uri") not with `xml:` attribute but rather `xmlns:`:

```
xmlns:cards="uri"
```

Then you need to use correctly you import statement: target an external xsd resource that is defining the elements belonging to namespace *uri*. Let's say you have another xsd called 'simpleTypes.xsd', this xsd is declaring `targetnamespace='uri'`, it is the one you have to import in your current XSD:

```
<xs:import namespace="uri" schemalocation="./simpleTypes.xsd"/>
```

To start with XML namespaces, I would advice starting with w3schools rather than looking at the W3C specifications.

Have a look at:

- http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_schema.asp